# count Query in sql

Tags: sql, count, subquery, sum

i have an issue with query

1st table (Master) Name :MainCategory  with fields (Category_id,Category_name)

2nd Table (Transation) Name : Incident with fields (Incident_id,Category_id,subject,description)

i want to query to count the appearance of category_id in the table Transation

for eg result can be

```
Category_name   Number_of_Faults

Hardware          10
Software          22
Network           17
```

thanks

Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Category_Name, COUNT(b.Incident_Id) Number_of_Faults
FROM MainCategory a JOIN Incident b
ON a.Category_id = b.Category_id
GROUP BY a.Category_Name
```

Comment: In many RDBM systems, one has to write: `GROUP BY a.Category_id, a.Category_Name`

Comment: @ypercube: You're right, but OP didn't tell us which SQL type he's using... so I tried this believing it could be correct. Thanks :)

Comment: @Marco: Most RDBMS will reject this GROUP BY because it doesn't match the SELECT list. IIRC, only MySQL allows such ambiguity

Comment: @Marco: It was not wrong before. But it would only work in systems (like MySQL) that support the inclusion (in the Select list) of fields that are functionally dependent on the fields in Group by list.

Comment: @gbn: It's not ambiguity when `a.Category_id` is primary key and (therefore) `a.Category_name` is functionally dependent on it.

Comment: @ypercube, yeah, I know, you are right!! I didn't take your comment as a critic, but as a good suggestion :)

Comment: @ypercube: I prefer explicitness. Your are correct there a functional dependency but without a unique constraint on Category_Name you could get different results. That is, you can have multiple Category_Name values for a single Category_id, no?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You need a LEFT JOIN to deal with "no incidents" for a given category

```
SELECT
    M.Category_Name,
    COUNT(I.Category_id) AS Number_of_Faults
FROM
    MainCategory M
    LEFT JOIN
    Incident I ON M.Category_id = I.Category_id
GROUP BY
    M.Category_name
```