# Query returns one row with complete sum instead of per-row sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 9 items in a problem_categories tables that have category_id = 1

When I do this query:

```
select problems.problem_id , problem_title , sum( vote ) as totalVotes 
from problems 
left join problem_votes on problems.problem_id = problem_votes.problem_id 
left join problem_categories on problems.problem_id = problem_categories.problem_id  
where problem_categories.category_id = 1;
```

I get 1 row with a complete sum of all the votes for the 9 items.  But what I was really looking for was the 9 rows with a vote sum for each.  Any idea what is wrong with my query just by looking at it?

My tables are

```
problem - lists problem information
problem_votes - has a record per vote for each problem
problem_categories - table keeping a problem_id and a category_id so that a problem can be in a certain category
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to tell MySQL what you're grouping by. Right now it thinks you want EVERYTHING grouped into one row. If you want it to by grouped by `problem_title`, then add in this line after your `WHERE`:

```
GROUP BY problem_title
```

This will cause you to get a different row for each unique `problem_title`, and the `sum` will only count records matching that title.

**Edit:**

So the whole query will look something like this:

```
select problems.problem_id , problem_title , sum( vote ) as totalVotes 
from problems 
left join problem_votes on problems.problem_id = problem_votes.problem_id 
left join problem_categories on problems.problem_id = problem_categories.problem_id  
where problem_categories.category_id = 1
group by problem_title;
```

Comment: it work, yes, but its only summing up the total votes of specific problem_title. Its not summing up everything. I don't think this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, most versions of SQL do not accept group by statements that do not include all non-aggregate columns. So if you're ever working with some other SQL software, you'll likely need to include problems.problem_id and problem_title.

For more on this issue, see this thread: [Do all columns in a SELECT list have to appear in a GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986127/do-all-columns-in-a-select-list-have-to-appear-in-a-group-by-clause)