# How do I use the GROUP BY function in Hive with the following query?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Here's my Hive Query:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE csp_filtered_data_table_b
SELECT CSP_CPCODE, CSP_ACSKEYWORDS, CSP_TARIFF_CODE, CSP_ERROR_CODE,
CONCAT(CSP_ARRAY_DATE[2], '-',
(
CASE CSP_ARRAY_DATE[1]
WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
ELSE '12'
END
), '-',
CSP_ARRAY_DATE[0]),
SUBSTR(CSP_TRANSACTION_TIME_DATE, 13,23),
CSP_MOBILE_NUMBER,
WEEKOFYEAR(
CONCAT(CSP_ARRAY_DATE[2], '-',
(
CASE CSP_ARRAY_DATE[1]
WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
ELSE '12'
END
), '-',
CSP_ARRAY_DATE[0])
)
FROM csp_formatted_date;
```

Now, I'm supposed to get the results grouped by the `CSP_ERROR_CODE`.

So I added the following:

```
GROUP BY CSP_CPCODE, CSP_ACSKEYWORDS, CSP_TARIFF_CODE, CSP_MOBILE_NUMBER, CSP_ERROR_CODE;
```

Though I need only group it by `CSP_ERROR_CODE`, it always returns an error (seen below) which can be fixed by putting in all the other fields. I have no idea what this means for table organization, but after doing just that in this case, it is giving me the following error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 3:7 Expression not in
>   GROUP BY key '2'

I usually encounter that error when I failed to put in the column name 'key', but where did key '2' come from, and how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: I went around it, but I never found the solution.

Comment: Is the error displayed is same if you you miss any column from select clause or group by?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in SQL - all non aggregation parts of the select statement must be included in the 'group by' statement, otherwise the processor does not know what to output for the non-grouped and non-aggregated fields.

See - [Do all columns in a SELECT list have to appear in a GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986127/do-all-columns-in-a-select-list-have-to-appear-in-a-group-by-clause)