# How to get only the second duplicated record in laravel 5.5?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say i have a user table like this :

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| ID | Name      | Email                | Age  |
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| 1  | John      | john.doe1@mail.com   | 24   |
| 2  | Josh      | josh99@mail.com      | 29   |
| 3  | Joseph    | joseph410@mail.com   | 21   |
| 4  | George    | gge.48@mail.com      | 28   |
| 5  | Joseph    | jh.city89@mail.com   | 24   |
| 6  | Kim       | kimsd@mail.com       | 32   |
| 7  | Bob       | bob.s@mail.com       | 38   |
| 8  | Joseph    | psa.jos@mail.com     | 34   |
| 9  | Joseph    | joseph.la@mail.com   | 28   |
| 10 | Jonathan  | jonhan@mail.com      | 22   |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+------+
```

In the actual, the database consists of more data and some of the data is duplicated, with more than two records. But the point is i want to get only the first and the second row of the duplicated rows that contains the name of "Joseph", How can i achieve this ? My code so far...

```
User::withTrashed()->groupBy('name')->havingRaw('count("name") >= 1')->get();
```

With that code the result will retrieve :

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| ID | Name      | Email                | Age  |
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| 1  | John      | john.doe1@mail.com   | 24   |
| 2  | Josh      | josh99@mail.com      | 29   |
| 3  | Joseph    | joseph410@mail.com   | 21   |
| 4  | George    | gge.48@mail.com      | 28   |
| 6  | Kim       | kimsd@mail.com       | 32   |
| 7  | Bob       | bob.s@mail.com       | 38   |
| 10 | Jonathan  | jonhan@mail.com      | 22   |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+------+
```

And i use this code to try to get the second duplicated row :

```
User::withTrashed()->groupBy('name')->havingRaw('count("name") >= 2')->get();
```

The result is still same as the mentioned above :

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| ID | Name      | Email                | Age  |
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| 1  | John      | john.doe1@mail.com   | 24   |
| 2  | Josh      | josh99@mail.com      | 29   |
| 3  | Joseph    | joseph410@mail.com   | 21   |
| 4  | George    | gge.48@mail.com      | 28   |
| 6  | Kim       | kimsd@mail.com       | 32   |
| 7  | Bob       | bob.s@mail.com       | 38   |
| 10 | Jonathan  | jonhan@mail.com      | 22   |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+------+
```

I want the result is to get record that have the id "5" with name "Joseph" like this :

```
    +----+-----------+----------------------+------+
    | ID | Name      | Email                | Age  |
    +----+-----------+----------------------+------+
    | 1  | John      | john.doe1@mail.com   | 24   |
    | 2  | Josh      | josh99@mail.com      | 29   |
    | 4  | George    | gge.48@mail.com      | 28   |
    | 5  | Joseph    | jh.city89@mail.com   | 24   |
    | 6  | Kim       | kimsd@mail.com       | 32   |
    | 7  | Bob       | bob.s@mail.com       | 38   |
    | 10 | Jonathan  | jonhan@mail.com      | 22   |
    +----+-----------+---------+------------+------+
```

But it seems only the first duplicate row is retrieved and i can't get the second duplicated row, can anybody give me suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start from your query

```php
User::withTrashed()->groupBy('name')->havingRaw('count("name") >= 1')->get();
```

This will show all groups of rows whose count equals to 1 ore more. and this is the description of `DISTINCT`.

If you want to get only duplicate records you should get groups whose count is LARGER than 1.

The other thing to notice here is that a non-aggrigated column will be chosen randomly. because when you get a name and it's count, for example if you select `name,count(name), email` (email is not in the group by clause - not aggregated), and 4  rows have the same name. so you'll see:

```
+--------+-------------+-------+
| Name   | Count(Name) | Email |
+--------+-------------+-------+
| Joseph | 4           | X     |
+--------+-------------+-------+
```

what do you expect instead of `X`? which one of the 4 emails?  actually, in SQLServer it's forbidden to select a non-aggrigated column and other databases will just give you a random one of the counted 3.
see this answer for more details it's explained very well: [Do all columns in a SELECT list have to appear in a GROUP BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986127/do-all-columns-in-a-select-list-have-to-appear-in-a-group-by-clause)

So, we'll use `having  count(name) > 1` and select only the aggregated column `name`

```php
DB::from('users')->select('name')->groupBy('name')->havingRaw('count("name") > 1')->get();
```

This should give you (didn't test it) this:

```
+--------+-------------+
| name   | Count(name) |
+--------+-------------+
| Joseph | 4           |
+--------+-------------+
```

This will give you all names who have 2 or more instances. you can determine the number of duplicates in the having clause. for example `having count(name)  = 3` will give you all names which have exactly 3 duplicates.

So how to get the second duplicate? I have a question for that:

What is the first (original) duplicate? is it the one with the oldest `created_at` or the oldest `updated_at` ? or maybe some other condition?. because of that you should make another query with `order by` clause to give you the duplicates in the order most convenient to you. for example:

```sql
select * from `users` where `name` in  (select `name` from users group by `name` having count(`name`) > 1) order by `id` asc
```

which will give:

```
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| ID | Name      | Email                | Age  |
+----+-----------+----------------------+------+
| 3  | Joseph    | joseph410@mail.com   | 21   |
| 5  | Joseph    | jh.city89@mail.com   | 24   |
| 8  | Joseph    | psa.jos@mail.com     | 34   |
| 9  | Joseph    | joseph.la@mail.com   | 28   |
+----+-----------+---------+------------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, your detailed answer especially the query solved the question!