# Group by on non id field

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following setup of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tags (
tag_id int4 NOT NULL,
creation_timestamp timestamp NULL,
"name" varchar(255) NULL,
CONSTRAINT tags_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tag_id)
);


-- public.tag_targets definition

-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public.tag_targets;

CREATE TABLE public.tag_targets (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    creation_timestamp timestamp NULL,
    target_id int8 NULL,
    target_name varchar(255) NULL,
    last_update_timestamp timestamp NULL,
    tag_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tag_targets_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fkcesi55mqvysjv63c1xf2j15oh FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES tags(tag_id)
);
```

I am trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tag_targets tt, tags t 
WHERE tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t."name" IN ('Keeper', 'Pk'))
GROUP by tt.target_id
```

However it wants the PK of both Tags and Tagtarget in the group by:

```
 ERROR: column "tt.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is there anyway to group on the target_id column? Also feel free to give any feedback on table design as I went for a generic mapping table and independent tags table

Comment: why you wanna group by? show us your desired output

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are requesting `SELECT *` but in `GROUP BY` you specified only `tt.target_id`. Generally speaking [All column names in SELECT list must appear in GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986127/do-all-columns-in-a-select-list-have-to-appear-in-a-group-by-clause). Oversimplifying: your database doesn't know what to do with all values you requested in select, that weren't used in `GROUP BY` or any agregate.

Try running following query to see if you are getting something

```
SELECT tt.target_id, count(*)
FROM tag_targets tt, tags t 
WHERE tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
AND (t."name" IN ('Keeper', 'Pk'))
GROUP by tt.target_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated but your syntax of table1, table2 with the join in the "where" clause is the non-ANSI syntax.  It's not wrong or anything, but the ANSI syntax of explicit joins is preferred for a litany of reasons I won't go into:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  tag_targets tt
  join tags t on
    tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
where
  t."name" IN ('Keeper', 'Pk')
```

On the surface, when you say group I am wondering if you mean "sort..."  I am assuming you are new to SQL, so if that's an oversimplification, forgive me, but this would be perhaps what you wanted -- an "order by" instead of a group by.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  tag_targets tt
  join tags t on
    tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
where
  t."name" IN ('Keeper', 'Pk')
order by
  tt.target_id
```

If, on the other hand, you only wanted a single record for each target_id (which is truly a "group by target_id"), then perhaps this is what you wanted...  one record per target_id, but then you have to identify how to prioritize which order is selected.  In this example, I say pick the one based on the most recent updated date:

```
SELECT distinct on (tt.target_id)
  *
FROM
  tag_targets tt
  join tags t on
    tt.tag_id = t.tag_id
where
  t."name" IN ('Keeper', 'Pk')
order by
  tt.target_id, tt.last_update_timestamp desc
```

Not confident on either of these suggestions, so if they miss the mark, post some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Nitpicking: the implicit joins in the WHERE clause are "ANSI joins" - just the outdated ones from before '89